# Running a CGI script on Yosemite/Apache from another computer

Tags: linux, apache, raspberry-pi, cgi, osx-yosemite

I am trying to run a simple cgi script which resides on my iMac (Yosemite installed) from a Windows 10 computer.

Here is the **say_test01** script (note that I tried with .cgi at the end but it also didn't work)

```
  #!/bin/bash

  echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n"

  cat << junk
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>
  saying
  </title>
  </head>
  <body>
  junk

  #-----------------------
  osascript -e "set volume 8"
  say -v Whisper This is just wrong!
  osascript -e "set volume 4"
  say -v Whisper This is OK!

  #-----------------------
  cat << junk
  </body>
  </html>
  junk
```

On the iMac I am running Apache v2.4.16.

On the iMac, from the terminal, I can enter *./say_test01* and I can hear the voice say the phrase.

Again, on the iMac, but from a browser, when I enter the *localhost/cgi-bin/say_test01* all I see are the contents of the file.

I understand, from reading other threads, that this is because the system doesn't know which application is associated with this file.

When I run from a browser on my Win10 PC the command *192.168.1.55/cgi-bin/saysomething* I either see the contents of the file displayed or I get the error message "This site can't be reached".

So I am looking for some help in figuring this out...

In the **httpd.conf** here are some excerpts:

**These lines have the '#' removed:**

```
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so

LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so

LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so

LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so

LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
```

Here is the **Directory** section:

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And  finally **this line has the '#' removed**

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

In the **httpd-userdir.conf** file, the following line has the **'#' removed**

Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf

In the **/etc/apache2/users** directory I have the file **Name.conf** which has the following code

```
<Directory "/Users/Name/Sites/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks    
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have not touched the virtual host file because I don't think (?) it applies here.

My ultimate goal is to pass parameters from another computer (raspberry pi) perhaps using python code to a cgi script so that the iMac can 'say' what I want... (e.g. today's weather, lights have just turned on...etc)

Any suggestions on how I can get this working?

**Edit:**

Using the suggestion of looking at the error log I saw that my httpd.conf had an error. The line ***Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI*** gave me an error message saying that I needed to have the '+' in front of all options or no options! So I changed the line to **Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI**. It now works well.

I now send a http GET statement from my ISY994i (Insteon controller) to the Raspberry pi3. On the pi I have setup a HTTPServer which waits for the GET statement. Once received, it triggers a python script on the pi which parses a weather xml file (which I previously created for my iRule app, using wunderground.com as the source) and extracts the current day's weather forecast, which is a text descriptive paragraph; it then re-formats the text forecast so that the iMac can say it properly; and finally, using urllib2, it triggers the iMac to 'say' the weather. I am still encountering a problem, on the pi, setting up the HTTPServer to run **automatically** on a reboot but it works well when I start it manually. I will open a new question to get help resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to point out is that scripts run through the web server are unlikely to have permissions to make things happen like having the computer speak. The web server user won't have permission to access that part of the system. You would be better off doing this through ssh.

However, in order to get you being able to run scripts through the web server, as asked, here goes:

You need to add the .cgi extension to your script. You have your handler set up for the .cgi extension:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

So it's only going to work for scripts that have that extension. Currently you have none. I know you say you tried it, but it's definitely not going to work without it. So put it back in, and see if it works now. If it doesn't, don't take it off again. It's needed. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: The interesting thing is that I had this working several years ago with an older version of OS and on the same iMac. However, the hard drive died and I lost most of the setup. I also upgraded the OS to Yosemite which seems to handle things differently than the OS I was on previously.  One of the items in particular is WebSharing. I also understood that I didn't need the .cgi if the script was located in the defined directory which is /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables for me!

Comment: You don't need the .cgi extension, but that requires a different configuration. With the configuration you have, it is needed. As I already explained. Have you tried adding it back in?

Comment: Ok I copied the file say_test01 and created say_test01,cgi. Now neither file works from the browser on the iMac! I'm not even seeing the contents of the file. The browser just seems to hang!Here is what I see with ls -l     -rwxr-xr-x  1 Sarah  wheel   429 Dec 13 14:28 say_test01
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Sarah  wheel   429 Dec 13 16:33 say_test01.cgi

Comment: What does the error log say? What do you see in view source?

Comment: Here are the recent error log items: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Garys-iMac.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Dec 13 17:21:08.274784 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3650] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 13 17:21:08.275000 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3650] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Dec 13 17:31:26.198376 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3650] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: I searched on the AF00558 error and the suggestion was to enter the line ServerName localhost into the httpd.conf. I did this and nothing seems to change! Interestingly, although the browser view still hangs there are no new entries in the error log!

Comment: When you say it hangs? What do you see? What is in view source? Nothing in the log is relevant to this problem.

Comment: And are you sure the web server is running?! The log sounds like it's shut down at the moment!

Comment: The log was down! I found an error in httpd.conf. I corrected that and restarted. The latest errors: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
[Wed Dec 14 00:34:21.603024 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25826] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.27 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 14 00:34:21.603079 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25826] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
The 1st two are from **httpd-vhosts.conf**. Do they need to fixed?

Comment: Note that the browser no longer hangs. I just see the content of the file. The same happens with and without the **.cgi**. On the Win10 PC I am getting the same... only the content.